# Redirect from weebly to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, weebly

I have a weebly website which I want to redirect it to a new wordpress site.

I have already tried this code "" to the header of weebly but nothing happens.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Change the DNS/forward settings for the domain so it points to the hosted WP site.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mynewsite.com/" />`

in the header, *if* Weebly allows javascript to be added to the header. This will keep your Weebly domain live and your domain pointed at Weebly.

But the easiest thing to do is go to your domain registrar and repoint the domain to the name-servers of the host of your new WordPress site. This is the best long term solution, if you are planning on abandoning Weebly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and maybe best way is to point your weebly domain to your new WP website. You can do it by changing the DNS records of your domain.